# После переноса сайта на WP пропал фавикон и описание

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть сайт http://brilgo.ru/. Его перенесли на новый домен https://brilgo.pro. Поменяли фавикон. При открытии по ссылке https://brilgo.pro фавикона в сафари не видно, или видно старый фавикон вместо нового.

Вот новый фавикон

[image: Logo]

Описание тоже пропадает. При копировании ссылки в Телеграм сообщение получается просто ссылкой, а должно быть с фавиконом и описанием. Как можно решить такую проблему? Возможно есть плагин который в этом поможет?

Comment: 1. Фавикон не имеет отношения к ТГ и тп. 2. если что см https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не надо пытаться подсовывать pdf файл в качестве иконки - браузеры его не понимают.

Comment: Там пробовали ставить svg, png. Итог был один и тот же. Поэтому там попробовали уже и PDF поставить.

Comment: @Denis а чё не exe? :)

Comment: Там правда они еще и размеры фавикона перепутали. Разберусь - отпишусь

Answer (score 0):

Сделал PNG и переименовал в ico. Иконка появилась

Comment: Переименование в ico - это какой-то бред, это изначально разные форматы файлов. Все современные браузеры должны нормально png понимать.